# Why is the kiss_fft's forward and inverse radix-4 calculation different?

Tags: c, fft, kissfft

I've been spending time understanding and implementing my own mixed radix decimation-in-time fast fourier transform. I've mostly been using kiss_fft and http://www.briangough.com/fftalgorithms.pdf to understand what's happening.

From what I've read, I can reverse an fft by using conjugate twiddle factors.

Yet when I read the kiss_fft source code, the radix-4 implementation actually tests if we are doing a forward or inverse transform, and uses slightly different maths.

https://github.com/itdaniher/kissfft/blob/master/kiss_fft.c#L77

```
    if(st->inverse) {
        Fout[m].r = scratch[5].r - scratch[4].i;
        Fout[m].i = scratch[5].i + scratch[4].r;
        Fout[m3].r = scratch[5].r + scratch[4].i;
        Fout[m3].i = scratch[5].i - scratch[4].r;
    }else{
        Fout[m].r = scratch[5].r + scratch[4].i;
        Fout[m].i = scratch[5].i - scratch[4].r;
        Fout[m3].r = scratch[5].r - scratch[4].i;
        Fout[m3].i = scratch[5].i + scratch[4].r;
    }
```

I thought that the fft calculations used are the *same* for forwards and reverse ffts (like it is for kiss_fft's radix-2, 3 and 5 implementations).

Why does kiss_fft radix-4 calculation need to do this?

Comment: It's just changing the sign of the imaginary component for each term, which is the same as taking the complex conjugate.

Comment: @PaulR should write it up as an answer. You might want to add the explanation
ifft(x) == conj(fft(conj(x)))  , subject to scaling constant

Comment: @PaulR Maybe I should have been more specific with my question. In the fft documentation, they say you can use the same radix-4 calculation for forwards and reverse (fftalgorithms.pdf equations 138 and 139). They make no mention that for t4 we need to take the conjugate for inverse direction (even though the twiddle factors are _already_ conjugates).

Comment: Just to point out **why** there is a radix-4 implementation: 4 is 2x2, so you could in theory leave the radix-4 out and just use radix-2 twice. But the radix-4 code as shown above happens to have extremely convenient factors - +1, -1, +i and -i. Logically, there's a complex multiplication, but the CPU just needs FP addition. The multiplication is implicit, but that also means you can't easily conjugate the multiplication factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same radix-4 computation kernel for an IFFT if you precede that computation by a vector complex conjugation.  Or you can skip doing a separate preceding vector complex conjugation operation, and use a different radix-4 compute kernel which has the conjugation built-in.

Doing the Radix-4 with the conjugation built-in might provide for better register re-use on some processor architectures.

Note that 2 complex conjugations are included within the equation relating an IFFT to an FFT.  Reverse rotating the twiddle factors only takes care on one of those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into the kiss_fft code some more, and that's whats happening. It also explains why the radix-3 and radix-5 take sin(pi/3) and sin(2pi/5), sin(2pi/10) from the twiddle array instead of hard coding them in the algorithm.

Could you put emphasis the last sentence? As that is actually the answer to my question, then I can mark it as answered.