# In kiss_fft, why does kf_bfly2 take an array as argument? The argument seems to be a scalar

Tags: c, fft, kissfft

[Kiss_fft](https://github.com/mborgerding/kissfft/blob/master/kiss_fft.c) is a pretty simple FFT implementation; it's almost textbook. It breaks down larger DFT's into repeated smaller FFT's, by factoring the FFT size. It has optimized butterfly functions for radix 2,3,4 and 5.

The 2,3 and 5 butterflies are small primes, commonly found when factoring, but the radix-4 butterfly is an optimized case that saves a few multiplications compared to using the radix-2 twice*. For instance, for a 32-point FFT, the size 32 is factored into 4x4x2 - two stages of `kf_bfly4` followed by one of `kf_bfly2`

However, this means you can only have one `kf_bfly2` stage. If your FFT size was a multiple of 4, you wouldn't have had two `kf_bfly2` stages, but a single `kf_bfly4` stage. And that also means that the `kf_bfly2` function works on "arrays" of length 1.

In code, the declaration is

```
static void kf_bfly2(kiss_fft_cpx * Fout, const size_t fstride, const kiss_fft_cfg st, int m)
```

where `Fout` is an "array" of size `m`, i.e. always 1. The butterfly loops over `Fout`, and the compiler of course can't do the numerical analysis to show that `m==1`. But since this is the last butterfly, it is called **quite** often.

**Q1)** Is my analysis correct? Is `kf_bfly2` indeed called only with `m==1`?

**Q2)** Assuming that this is indeed a missed optimization, there are two possible approaches. We could just drop the `m` parameter from `kf_bfly2`, or we could change the factor analysis to factor 32 as 2x4x4 (move `kf_bfly2` up front, call it once at top level for arrays of size 4x4=16). What would be best?

[*]
The radix-4 butterfly ends up having factors +1,-1, +i and -i, which can be implemented as additions and subtractions instead. See [Why is the kiss_fft's forward and inverse radix-4 calculation different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401102/why-is-the-kiss-ffts-forward-and-inverse-radix-4-calculation-different)

Comment: The author, @Mark Borgerding, is active on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3343/mark-borgerding

Comment: @PaulR: I had noticed his comment on the linked question :)

Comment: Sorry - I didn't notice that - I just thought it might be worth pinging him as I've seen him answer kiss-fft questions on here in the past. :)

Comment: BTW, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542873/why-is-the-kiss-ffts-forward-and-inverse-radix-4-calculation-different-part-2.

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

The question has a one-off error. The function doesn't follow the usual convention; `m==1` is the upper bound. The input is in fact an array of length 2, not a scalar. The remainder of the answer below is correct, and there's indeed an optimization possible

## Optimized code (also for C++)

[GitHub](https://github.com/MSalters/kissfft)

### Original answer

To understand the value of "m", it helps to understand how Kiss FFT works: it turns a large FFT recursively into smaller FFT's, by factoring the FFT size. And there are multiple possible factorizations: 32 is 4x4x2 but also 2x4x4.

Now that `m` parameter in `kf_bfly2` and the other butterfly functions is the product of all the factors that follow. So, using 32 again as an example, `kf_bfly4` will be called with m=8 and m=2.

I thought that `m=1` in `kf_bfly2` because in my tests it always happened to be the last factor, *if* it was a factor. If you use a 221 point FFT, the last factor will be 17, not 2.

But 34 is factored as 2x17, and in that case `m==17`. There is no special reason for this, this just happens to be an artifact of the implementation of `kf_factor`. It tests factorization by checking `n%4, n%2, n%3, n%5, n%7, n%9, n%11 ...`. That's not the most effective way, of course. `Checking n%9` is pointless as you already found two factors of 3 earlier.

But note from the position of `n%4` there is freedom in checking the factors. We can simply check `n%2` last. If we do this, then 34 will factor as `17x2` instead of `2x17`. This may seem like a trivial optimization, but it does allow us to remove the loop in `kf_bfly2`. In addition, it now only uses the first twiddle factor - and that is a very convenient `{1 + 0i}`. So the only multiplication in `kf_bfly2` is also eliminated.

The optimizations don't stop here - since `kf_bfly2` is now a whole lot smaller, and there is only one call site*, your compiler will likely inline `kf_bfly2` into `kf_work`. And we know from the changed factoring that `2` can only be the last factor, so we can stop the recursion in `kf_work` as well.

### TL;DR

When you change the order of factorization, you unlock multiple optimizations in a row.

- * Footnote:
  There's one special case, the OpenMP optimization will use multiple threads for the top-level, if that is small enough. Turning a 2x17 FFT into a 17x2 FFT will mean the second thread is no longer used, but that was a bit pointless anyway for such a small FFT.

Comment: Considering your kwowledge of kissFFT guts, I would like to kindly ask for your feedback on this currently opened PR: https://github.com/mborgerding/kissfft/pull/84

Comment: @JulienM: I've personally never looked into the fixed-point side, sorry